# Transfer between iPod users

Tags: ipod, data-transfer

My son would like to pass off his iPod to his brother since he has a phone now. I switched to my other son's Apple ID from his iPad but how do I get rid of the stuff on the iPod while keeping it on the iPhone? And also keep the stuff on the iPad while putting it on the iPod?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Plug it it up to the computer and if it's set to sync stop it,and set the settings to manage manually. This makes it possible for you to content on the device without loosing anything.